# Swing-style automatic layout in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to create a GWT form without manually specifying sizes of components ?

I'm looking for layout managers that work a bit like in Swing, where you can simply pack things in a panel with a proper layout manager and constraints and never care about size/width/height. However it seems like in GWT all typical layouts (eg. Dock, Horizontal/Vertical) either require size parameter or don't exist (GridBag, unless you count in very limited FlexTable).

Answer (score 0):

Such layout exists in GXT, but I would recommend to use plain-old CSS + HTMLPanel. It will give you in the end the same result, but in a little bit different way.